# iOS custom keyboard clicks sound

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, settings, customization

Is there a way to customise the sound of the `keyboard click` that can be turned on / off under:

`Settings > Sounds > Keyboard Clicks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No. You're stuck with the sounds in the interface Apple provides, which have default settings for ringtone, text tone, new voicemail, new mail, sent mail, calendar alerts, reminder alerts and airdrop.

You *can* customize entries in Contacts to use alternate sounds and ringtones for texts and calls, but that's it.

It *may* be possible to change the click sound if you jailbreak your iPhone, but I'm just guessing.